# Do i need to join Graphics Card with CPU fan

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, speedfan

Initially i had inno `3d 256MB Nvidia GTS graphics card`.
I also had another Big FAN above the processor (Vendor put in quad core)
In that card there was one cable which was joined with that FAN.

Now i have changed the CARD to `1GB Nvidia GT9600` . But there is no pins to join the fan with that card.

Is it ok . i don't know why old card was joined with FAN

Answer (score 1):

Don't!

Unless you have some mad water cooling system where everything is connected, there is simply no need.

Your CPU should have a heat-sink with a fan and so should your graphics card, they should be separate and not touching or integrated.

If you think this is wrong, please post a picture of the inside of your case, as you must have some weird setup I haven't seen.

Comment: I can't say it was wrong as it was running for almost 2 years.
But now my FAN is ruiing all day and night and its not stopping.

If it runs can it do any harm to processor

Comment: No - the fan should be on 24x7, just running slow when your machine is not at full load.

Comment: If it runs at full load all the time will it be a problem. i am using heavy application running 24x7

Comment: It won't technically be a problem, but when you say full load - make sure it is connected properly and you have a 4 pin fan (that has variable speed control)... Simply, it should work, but you may find the life of it go down hill.